# how to put php code in a php if else statement

Tags: php, if-statement, variables

I am trying to run specific php code depending upon what site is the URL.

the issue is that our dev team does not want to create another page, but there are 2 pages which use the same file ( the one i pasted below ).  I need one page to use the data returned when the if statement is false, and if its true it doesnt need any other data to run...

I am trying to explain this the best i can, please forgive me if its confusing.

My code below works as in it says true or false. I need to run the below if its false and nothing if its true.

use this if false :

```
$primaryCta = [
  'text' => $data['spclprictatxt'],
  'href' => $data['spclprictalnk'],
];"
```

use nothing if true

```
<?php
    use Febe\Helper\BeautifyText;
    $image = $data['image'][0] ?? null;

    $link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://" .
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $pageCk = $link;

    $primaryCta = "false";

    $primaryCta1 = "true";

    if ($link === 'http://heiferdev.local/account/login.html') {
             echo $primaryCta1;
             echo $link;
    } else {
             echo $primaryCta;
             echo $link;
    }
?>

<div class="headerSimple"
    <?= !empty($data['background_color']) ? 'data-background-color="' . $data['background_color'] . '"' : ''; ?>
>
    <div class="wrappers__wrapper-max">
        <div class="headerSimple__header">

            <?php if(!empty($image)): ?>
                <figure class="headerSimple__figure">
                    <?= $this->returnView(
                        'shared/dynamicImage/dynamicImage',
                        [
                            "source" => IMGIX_URL . $image['url'],
                            "alt" => $image['alt-text'],
                            "focalPoint" => $image['focal-point'],
                            "focalPointZoom" => $image['focal-point-zoom'],
                            "parameters" => $image['parameters'],
                            "imgClass" => "headerSimple__figure-img"
                        ]
                    );?>
                </figure>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <div class="wrappers__wrapper">
                <div class="headerSimple__headings">
                    <?php if(!empty($data['title'])) : ?>
                        <h1 class="headerSimple__title">
                            <?= BeautifyText::beautifyTitle($data['title']); ?>
                        </h1>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php if(!empty($data['lead_in_text']) || !empty($data['subhead'])) : ?>
            <div class="wrappers__wrapper">
                <?php if(!empty($data['subhead'])) : ?>
                    <h2 class="headerSimple__subhead">
                        <?= BeautifyText::beautifyText($data['subhead']); ?>
                    </h2>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if(!empty($data['lead_in_text'])) : ?>
                     <div class="headerSimple__body">
                        <?= BeautifyText::beautifyText($data['lead_in_text'], false); ?>

                        <div class="homeHeader__cta-block">
                            <?php if (!empty($primaryCta['href']) && !empty($primaryCta['text'])) :  ?>
                                <div class="homeHeader__cta-block">
                                    <a class="button__secondary button__medium js-product-add-to-basket" href="<?= $primaryCta['href']; ?>">
                                        <?= $primaryCta['text']; ?>
                                        <img style="margin-bottom: -8px;" 
                                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/white-dollar-sign-11549435997nrl2vmgejx.png" 
                                            alt="Money Icon" 
                                            width="30px" 
                                            height="38px" >
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Writing together does not significantly slow down performance, but splitting it into two files will only increase I/O costs (although the impact is minimal).

Comment: I didnt want to put it into my question since i didnt think it would help, however. I am a new developer at a firm and the system that is in place is new and custom.  So in this case, we are wanting to add a feature in our backend ( which i have already done and it works ), but the file that i had to edit for this, is used by two pages.

the second page (login) does not use all the features and only needs a few small things to work.  Thus throwing an error with the new code I add in for the new feature.

By adding in an if statement, I can tell the php to use one set of data for one page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to get this working. And it works flawlessly.

hope it may help others down the road...

```
$link = "http://heiferdev.local/";

    if ( $link != (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://" .
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) {
        $image = $data["image"][0] ?? null;
    } else {
        $image = $data["image"][0] ?? null;
        $primaryCta = [
            "text" => $data["spclprictatxt"],
            "href" => $data["spclprictalnk"],
        ];
    }
```